# LibreOffice or Excel: Randomization of items across colums without repetition

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have 100 people and I want them to judge words as either positive or negative (e.g. 'insurance' and 'car accident'). I have a total of 100 of such words. I also want each person to do three words as I am interested in some statistical properties (i.e. seeing how well people agree).

I want assign words to people by creating three columns with the same words in each column. However, I want words to randomized in a way so that there is no repetition in any row. Randomization is obviously important as I want to avoid any bias, but it would be silly to ask the same person the same two (or worse, three) words.

So, here is the data structure that I try to achieve:

```
person1, word1, word65, word33;
person2, word55, word56, word44;
person3, word23, word23, word3; <--- This should not happen
```

Is there a simple formula or other way to do this form of column-spanning randomization without repetition in LibreOffice Calc or Excel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are prepared to press recalculate a few times, you should get a sheet without any repeats without doing anything elaborate.

Comment: When I use 100 words, I get on average about 2-4 matches (tried about 10 times so far). Since I cannot have any pairs be the same (column 2 and 3, column 2 and 4, and column 3 and 4 must not be the same word)...

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want to be able to do that with very different amounts of words: it should work for 1000 words, but also for 100 and 30. I am sure the probably for a 1000 words is much more in my favour than with 100 or 30...

Comment: With 1000 words and 1000 people, took 5 times to get no repetition within a row when I tried it just now. But I agree, if you want to use fewer words this way won't be any good. I would be thinking about VBA but others may come up with an alternative. BTW I had to set up a similar thing for a family member and did end up using VBA,

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a random permutation of the words that you type in difference cells. You can do this task using the Libreoffice extension Permutate! (download here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/permutate/). Since I am the developer of this simple extension, please do not hesitate to ask for any clarifications.